# JetBrains WebStorm intellisense

Tags: javascript, intellisense, webstorm, ecmascript-5

When I see the intellisense menu in WebStorm, it shows little circular icons with lettering on them (i.e. "v", "m", "f", "p").

Does anyone know what all the icons mean, or know where there is a reference to understanding WebStorm's intellisense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the [icons reference](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/symbols.html) in WebStorm help.

- `v` - variable
- `m` - method
- `f` - field
- `p` - parameter