# Does WebStorm have intellisense like VSCode？

Tags: webstorm

[image: Like this]

Does WebStorm have intellisense of function like VSCode?

With index of node_modules WebStorm still can't give tips like this picture. How to open this feature?

Answer (score 3):

> Does WebStorm have intellisense of function like VSCode?

Yes, **it does**.

Among the [features](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/features/) of WebStorm you can find that

> *The IDE analyzes your project to provide the best code completion results for all supported languages. Hundreds of built-in inspections
>   report any possible issues right as you type and suggest quick-fix
>   options.*

On the official web page of WebStorm you can find as well more detailed info about [Intelligent coding assistance](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/features/coding-assistance.html).

> With index of node_modules WebStorm still can't give tips like this picture. How to open this feature?

It is hard to tell without knowing your specific Configuration (IDE, json file, etc) but you might want to try [Enable code completion for node_modules in WebStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39346505/enable-code-completion-for-node-modules-in-webstorm).

And lastly, there is a lot of related questions you may find useful:

- [JetBrains WebStorm intellisense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12215159/jetbrains-webstorm-intellisense)
- [How to enable intellisense in package.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42166160/how-to-enable-intellisense-in-package-json)
- [How do I enable Webstorm intellisense for AngularJS when writing CoffeeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18876863/how-do-i-enable-webstorm-intellisense-for-angularjs-when-writing-coffeescript)
- [WebStorm and TypeScript intellisense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31507271/webstorm-and-typescript-intellisense)
- [WebStorm - TypeScript and allowSyntheticDefaultImports flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35171858/webstorm-typescript-and-allowsyntheticdefaultimports-flag)
- [Enable Bootstrap Intellisense using Angular 4 in WebStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44205170/enable-bootstrap-intellisense-using-angular-4-in-webstorm)